# jQuery not working on clicking radiobutton

Tags: jquery, radio-button

my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("document ready");

    $("input[type=radio]").click(function(event){
        alert("clicked");
    });
});
```

But no alert shows up... And, when typing in on the console:
 `$(document).ready(function(){ alert("document ready");})` I get the alert! What is going on here?

Comment: Where does this code live? Is it in a `<script>` tag?

Comment: How about an example on jsFiddle?

Comment: (working) fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xnyWd/

Comment: Your code works on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lkxtv/1/ So the problem maybe that is there only one radio button or more than one?Which version of jquery you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, it explains as well why it does work in JSFiddle.
The problem was how I imported jQuery: I did

`<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuerylink" />`

and it had to be

`<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuerylink" ></script>`

I don't know why this is so, but now it works. Thanks for all effort.

Answer (score 4):

try [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) instead of .click()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("document ready");
    $("input[type=radio]").change(function(){
        alert("clicked");
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, I already looked for something like that, but could not find it!

Comment: From the jQuery docs: This event is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){

    $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
      alert("clicked");
    });        

});​
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/Dw6Fp/2/

Answer (score 0):

According to the jQuery selector docs **<sup>[[link](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)]</sup>** you should enclose parameter value with double quotes:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(event){
```

OR

```
$("input[type=\"radio\"]").click(function(event){
```

**UPDATE:** [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/RXcYy/)