# Triggering a click on radio button checks conditions before toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, radio-button, click

Sorry for the somewhat vague title, but I'll try to explain better. I wrote up some quick code in [this](https://codepen.io/ftahir192/pen/wyPKgv) codepen to show my problem.

Essentially, my codepen has two toggle buttons, "Male" and "Female" for ease. I also have a button and a click listener attached: `$('#doClick').click(function() {...}`.

When the button is clicked, the click listener toggles the female button by calling `$("#female").click();`

My issue is that when the page first loads up and "Male" is selected by default, pressing the button changes the toggle button, but it still spits out "Male is checked" in the console. So essentially, the `if` condition in the click listener is checked **before** the radio button is actually toggled to "Female".

This is part of a bigger piece of code where different code is executed depending on what is currently selected, so in my code, incorrect code is being executed due to the timing of the toggle and the condition check.

I hope my problem is described well.

I'm wondering if anybody knows why this is so, and what I can do to fix this? The following code fixes this:

```
$('#male').click(function() {
  console.log("Male was checked")
});

$('#female').click(function() {
  console.log("Female was checked")
});
```

but I'm not sure two different click listeners are necessary, and was wondering if there is a better solution.

Thanks

Comment: You could use 1 listener and check the `event` object for the `id` of the clicked element.

Comment: use `change` event

Comment: `$('#male, #female').change(function() { ...` bind `change` for radio not `click`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery not working on clicking radiobutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751035/jquery-not-working-on-clicking-radiobutton)

Comment: @Feathercrown. Thanks for the suggestion. I'm wondering if you have a code example for the toy suggestion? ArtemSky, I didn't think of that - good shout, thanks. I'll need to look through my code and see if there's any implications of doing so. I'm wondering if anybody happens to know why this actually happens but works fine using vanilla JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code almost had it, just need to change the binding to use `change` instead of `click` for the radios

```
$('#male, #female').on('change', function() {

  console.log("A click was registered");

  if($("#male").is(":checked")) {
    console.log("Male is checked");
  } else if($("#female").is(":checked")) {
    console.log("Female is checked");
  }

});
```

I prefer you do the check for which box is checked so that you an set female or male to check on load and your code will still work properly.

Documentation on jquery `change`

> Bind an event handler to the "change" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element

https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Thank you. I like this answer the most and it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a custom event and call it just after the programatically call of event `click´.

*This approach is useful if you really need to execute the `click` event programatically.*

**I.E:**

```
$('#female').on('radiobuttonChecker', function() {
  if($("#male").is(":checked")) {
    console.log("Male is checked");
  } else if($("#female").is(":checked")) {
    console.log("Female is checked");
  }  
});
```

```js
$('#male, #female').click(function(e) {
  console.log("A click was registered");
});

$('#female').on('radiobuttonChecker', function() {
  if($("#male").is(":checked")) {
    console.log("Male is checked");
  } else if($("#female").is(":checked")) {
    console.log("Female is checked");
  }  
});

$('#doClick').click(function() {
  $("#female").click();
  $("#female").trigger('radiobuttonChecker');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="male" checked> Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="female"> Female<br>


<button id="doClick">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - quite a cool trick. Although I think the `change` solution is a lot easier to implement.

Comment: @user3186023 you're welcome.  You need to choose what's better :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `change` event instead :

```
$('#male').change(function() {
  console.log("Male was checked")
});

$('#female').change(function() {
  console.log("Female was checked")
});
```

Comment: Why does this need to be done with 2 different change events? Couldn't we do `$('#male, #female').change(function() { if ($("#male"}.is(:checked) ... )`?

Comment: @user3186023 you are binding to 2 elements in either case, but it is better to do the check for which one is checked because if you were ever to check the female box first on load, this code will malfunction